# Formatting phone number give wrong output

Tags: javascript

My output is not formatted how I want it.

I get `(123) 4567890-` but I want `(123) 456-7890`

```js
  // Display as Phone number: (123) 456-7890
    var num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 0];

    var zip = [];
    var mid = [];
    var last = [];

    for (i=0; i< 10; i++) {
     if (i < 3) {
      zip.push(num[i]);
     } else if (2 < i < 6) {
      mid.push(num[i]);
     } else {
      last.push(num[i]);
     }

    }

    console.log('(' + zip.join("") + ') ' + mid.join("") + '-' + last.join(""));
```

Comment: `2 < i < 6` this does not do what you probably want.

Comment: `if (2 < i < 6)` does not do what you think it does. I also see almost no point in a loop for this.

Comment: Won't you effectively be asking `if (true < 6)` in that else if...?

Comment: More precisely, `<` is left-associative, in other words, it behaves like `(2 < i) < 6` which is always true. You should use `2 < i && i < 6`

Comment: You are better off using `slice` here: `let zip = num.slice(0, 3).join('')`

Answer (score 0):

With your original code, `(2 < i < 6)` is where it goes wrong.

It says *"if 2 is less than i, and its result is less than 6"*. That will always be true since the `boolean` expression *"2" is less than "i"* will either be true or false, and as true/false resolves to 1/0 it will always be smaller than 6.

Instead use only `(i < 6)`. It will catch *i* less than 6, but will never get those less than 3 as they will be captured in your first *if* statement.

```js
// Display as Phone number: (123) 456-7890
var num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

var zip = [];
var mid = [];
var last = [];

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i < 3) {
    zip.push(num[i]);
  } else if (i < 6) {
    mid.push(num[i]);
  } else {
    last.push(num[i]);
  }
}

console.log('(' + zip.join("") + ') ' + mid.join("") + '-' + last.join(""));
```

---

Here are a couple other approaches which you might find simpler.

Using [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to inject the parenthesis and dash into the array

```js
var num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 0];

console.log( formatMyNumber(num) ); 

function formatMyNumber(arr) {
  arr.splice(0, 0, "(");
  arr.splice(4, 0, ") ");
  arr.splice(8, 0, "-");  
  return arr.join('');
}
```

or [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) combined with [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and *cut out* the 3 number ranges

```js
var num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 0];

console.log( formatMyNumber(num) ); 

function formatMyNumber(a) {
  a = a.join('');
  return `(${a.slice(0,3)}) ${a.slice(3,6)}-${a.slice(6)}`;
}
```

or just concat with [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
var num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 0];

console.log( formatMyNumber(num) ); 

function formatMyNumber(a) {
  a = a.join('');
  return '(' + a.slice(0,3) + ') ' + a.slice(3,6) + '-' + a.slice(6);
}
```